# MySQL & PHP - Select 6 rows, each with a different 'WHERE' clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm pretty good with MySQL, but this is something I have never done. What I want to do is make an SQL code to select 6 rows, each with their own WHERE clause.

What I am trying to do is get 6 rows, and each will be the most recent "video" that was posted. there are 6 categories, so that's why I have 6 rows. I want it to pull the most recent by it 'id' number.

I'd do it with 6 different SQL queries, but I assume that would be slower (unless this is the only way to do this?)

[image: Layout]

From that small snippet, I would like to end up with is this:

2 --> 21

6 --> 16

8 --> 14 (Picks 14 since it's largest.)

---

**Final Working Code**

```
$sql="SELECT video_category, MAX(video_id) AS video_id FROM videos GROUP BY video_category";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $rows['video_category'] . " --> " . $rows['video_id'] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Group By category and max(id) probably.

Comment: Six `WHERE` clause in a single SQL statement???

Comment: We will need to see your table structure.

Comment: Please see the results for the "greatest-n-per-group" tag -- this is a very common request

Comment: I added the layout of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting the table structure. This is just a simple `GROUP BY` with a `MAX` aggregate on video_id.

```
SELECT video_category, MAX(video_id) AS video_id FROM videos GROUP BY video_category;
```

Comment: I'm not getting the video_id's with the result. I'll post the code up top.

Comment: That's a ripoff of my answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

something like

```
select distinct category, video_id from table_name order by id DESC
```

If you have 6 categories in the db, you would get 6 rows, all having highest id in their category

Comment: By 'distinct category' do you mean the category column name?

Comment: Yes, I posted the answer before he added the table details

Answer (score 2):

Please share your table structure. Nevertheless, i think the following query should do the trick:

```
SELECT category_id, MAX(movie_id) most_recent_movie_for_category FROM movies GROUP BY category_id
```

Comment: What is 'most_recent_movie_for_category' supposed to be filled in with?

Comment: thats just the last movie id added for each category

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Determine common WHERE clause that will result in what you need.
2. (probably preferred one) Make some query involving UNION (`SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... UNION SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...` etc.)

Let me know if you have any questions. I believe without your database structure it would be hard to help you more.

Comment: I posted it at the top if that helps you.